# two double spaces above heading iff text is above

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, line-spacing

My dissertation style guide specifies double spacing throughout, and two double spaces above section or subsection headings if there is text above the heading but a normal double space if there is another heading above.

I don't even know where to begin but here is a MWE of what I have so far.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\normalsize\centering}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter}{0pt}{\normalsize}

\titleformat{\section}
{\normalfont\normalsize\centering}{\thesection}{1em}{}

\titleformat{\subsection}
{\normalfont\normalsize\centering}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}

\titlespacing{\chapter} {0pt}{.5in}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\section} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection} {0pt}{0pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Test}
\subsection{More}
\lipsum[1]

Want two double spaces below this line.

\subsection{test}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE results]